# Java Type mismatch: cannot convert from MimeBodyPart to BodyPart

Tags: java, email

i'm trying to send email with attachment as it said here  [enter link description here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm) but my eclipse allways gives me this error:

**Type mismatch: cannot convert from MimeBodyPart to BodyPart**

and

**Type mismatch: cannot convert from MimeMultipart to Multipart**

this is my import libraries:

```
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.internet.MimeMultipart;
```

and this is the code where error appears:

```
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
```

what am i doing wrong?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You want `MimeMultipart` and `MimeBodyPart` from the `javax.mail.internet` package instead. See the Javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html).

The classes you have relate to SOAP messaging stuff.