# How to add a MimeMultipart to another one?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

This is possibly a very stupid question, but I'm trying to compose an Email message like [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19102191/581205)

- multipart/mixed

  - multipart/alternative

    - text/html
    - text/plain
  - attachment 1
  - attachment 2

So I'm having

```
MimeMultipart altPart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

BodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
textPart.setContent("someText", "text/plain");
altPart.addBodyPart(textPart);

BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlPart.setContent("someHtml", "text/html");
altPart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

MimeMultipart mixedPart = new MimeMultipart("multipart/mixed");
```

and need to add `altPart` to `mixedPart`, but I can't as the only adding method accepts `BodyPart` only. WTF?

<sup>Note that unlike [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19612288/581205), I'm not mixing up packages.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your `MimeMultipart` in another `MimeBodyPart`, using the `MimeBodyPart.setContent(Multipart mp)` method. Then you can add the `MimeBodyPart` to the `mixedPart` Object:

```
MimeMultipart alternativeMultipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

BodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
textPart.setContent("someText", "text/plain");
alternativeMultipart.addBodyPart(textPart);

BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlPart.setContent("someHtml", "text/html");
alternativeMultipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

MimeBodyPart alternativeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
alternativeBodyPart.setContent(alternativeMultipart);

MimeMultipart mixedMultipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");
mixedMultipart.addBodyPart(alternativeBodyPart);

MimeBodyPart textPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
textPart1.setContent("someOtherText", "text/plain");
mixedMultipart.addBodyPart(textPart1);
```