# Cannot resolve method 'getLabels(java.lang.String)'

Tags: java, guava, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to convert a MultiLabelDataset to a Multimap because I want to print its contents in a readable form.

The following code is close to accomplishing that, but yet... so far.

The trouble is with the line `result.putAll( key, dataset.getLabels( key ));` how to fix this issue?

```
public static Multimap<String, String> toMultimap(MultiLabelDataset<String, String> dataset)
{
    Multimap<String, String> result = HashMultimap.create();
    for (String key : ((LabeledLDADataset) dataset).items())
    {
        result.putAll( key, dataset.getLabels( key ));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Any specific error message?

Comment: the error message is in the name of the post

Comment: You posted this question 6 hours ago while I replaced `String` by `Item` in my answer 7 hours ago. However, this is something you really should try harder to find out. No `getLabels(String)`? So is there maybe a different `getLabels`? What actually `items()` returns?

Comment: @maaartinus yes, that is true. but surely you can understand the insane depravity of a programmer trying to make something work and staring with utter horror at the serpentine red line under some pernicious error in the IDE. I made that change but still it persists! I'm really going crazy. According to [the documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.3/scaladocs/edu/stanford/nlp/tmt/model/llda/LabeledLDADataset.html) that should work, but still nothing, i think it has to do with my faulty choices of import statements, what would be the correct imports?

Comment: How should I know? It's on your computer, not mine and I'm hearing about the `MultiLabelDataset` for the very first time. It doesn't seem to be well known. So I'd suggest you to provide the exact link to the jar file and post or provide your whole code. Then someone might try to fix it..., usually compile-time errors take a few seconds (though I gave up [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549863/how-to-add-a-mimemultipart-to-another-one) after half an hour, but this was a rare exception).